# If first param is true, then must pass second param in function

Tags: kotlin, arguments, variadic-functions

I have my custom Kotlin's function:

```
fun getActiveCartTest(isAsync: Boolean = false, vararg callback: Callback<Cart> ): TransportResponse? {
...
}
```

It has one **default** param (`isAsync`) and one **optional** (`vararg`) callback param.
I can call this function from java like this:

```
1.  TransportResponse transportResponse = TransportService.INSTANCE.getActiveCartTest();
2.  TransportResponse transportResponse = TransportService.INSTANCE.getActiveCartTest(false);
3.  TransportResponse transportResponse = TransportService.INSTANCE.getActiveCartTest(true);
4.  TransportService.INSTANCE.getActiveCartTest(true, new DefaultRestClientCallback<Cart>() {
            @Override
            public void onTransportResponse(@NotNull TransportResponse transportResponse) {

            }
        });
```

Nice, it works.
But, when I use this call:

```
TransportResponse transportResponse = TransportService.INSTANCE.getActiveCartTest(true);
```

I get a compile error.

What I mean. When client wants to call **async** call of function `getActiveCartTest` then it **MUST** use two params: `isAsync` **AND** `callback`.

As you can see in my function `getActiveCartTest` the client can omit second param (`callback`). It's not correct.

I need if first param `isAsync = true`, then user also **must** pass second param callback. And if first param `isAsync = false` then user can omit second param (`callback`)

Is it possible in Kotlin?

Answer (score 9):

Instead of trying to make code that nobody will be able to understand, why not divide your function in `getActiveCartTestSync` and `getActiveCartTestAsync`. The thing you want might be achievable by using reflection, however you make the code much more complicated without any reason.

Comment: Good idea. This is usually a good approach to take when you have functions with boolean parameters.